# How can a Netty server cancel receiving a response from a web server?

Tags: proxy, server, client, netty

Does anyone know the best way for a netty server handler to cancel receiving data from a web server? I have a server handler which proxies HttpRequests to a web server. However, when the requesting client cancels the request, I would like to stop receiving data on my server channel from the web server without closing the connection between the server handler and the web server.

Does anyone know how I can go about doing this. Your response would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: http does not have any stop sending system outside disconnecting the connection

Answer (score 0):

You could call `channel.config().setAutoRead(false)` this will tell netty to stop reading from the `Channel`. Once you want to start reading again just call `channel.config().setAutoRead(false)`.