# Java input on netty client side

Tags: java, input, netty, system.in

I am actually programming a client - server program using Netty, but I am stuck in a problem I cannot solve since last week.

Since it's a pretty big program, I cannot paste all my code but, I started using this example from Netty's github (https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/securechat)

In a context of a game, I would like to allow the player to type every command he likes (to change his name, or to see what's going on) but the thing is, during the input process, I can't receive the server answer.

The server answer is received through a callback :

```
public class ClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        System.out.println(cause.getMessage());
        ctx.close();
        System.exit(84);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, String answer) throws Exception {
       // HERE
    }
}
```

And in my main loop I am actually doing this (I simplified it because it's too long) :

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line;
line = in.readLine();
// Process and send to server
System.out.println(line);
```

When I am waiting for an input of the user and receiving the server answer at the same time, the input is blocking my callback. I only receive it when the input is done.

Can someone enlighten me please ? How can I proceed to make a non-blocking input or whatever so when the server actually sends me something, I can stop the input process and read the answer ?

Thank you !

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You receive an answer from the server before the user made an input?

Comment: Actually, when I'm doing the "line = in.readLine()", I am likely to receive an answer from the server but I can't get it. Example : there is 5 players. The player 5 is playing and I am typing something to send to the server. When the player finishes his turn, the game (for whatever reason) is over : so the game should restart from the beginning and notify all the players. But since the player 1, 2, 3, and I are stuck in the readLine() process, we can NOT get the server's notification (the callback is not called, but normally, it should). We will only get it when we'll pass the readLine part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40668791/how-can-a-netty-server-cancel-receiving-a-response-from-a-web-server This might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should decouple your input loop from the netty handlers.

If you start your game input loop from the netty handler, it will mean the netty thread never makes it back to the core of netty, and thus your channel is being marked as busy, meaning that new inputs will queue up, and will only be processed when the thread returns.

A good way to solve this problem is making a new thread instance right of the start of your programs, and making that thread call methods of netty to do your game actions.